# Need calrification regarding HornetQ <address-setting>

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1.final and I would like to define 2 different DLQ's, one for a certain queue and the other for all the rest of the queues.

I found this configuration :

```
<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="jms.queue.exampleQueue">
      <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.deadLetterQueue</dead-letter-address>
      <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
      <redelivery-delay>5000</redelivery-delay>
      <expiry-address>jms.queue.expiryQueue</expiry-address>
      <last-value-queue>true</last-value-queue>        
      <max-size-bytes>100000</max-size-bytes>
      <page-size-bytes>20000</page-size-bytes>
      <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
      <send-to-dla-on-no-route>true</send-to-dla-on-no-route>
      <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

The match attribute can be used to match a certain queue, I have a couple of questions regarding this configuration:

1. If I define 2 `address-setting`, one with a wild card to match all and one that matches only one queue, does the one queue definition take precedence? Do i need to put it before the match all definition or it does not matter?
2. In the example they match a queue `jms.queue.exampleQueue`, i have a queue defined as:

   ```
   <jms-queue name="MissionResult">
       <entry name="queue/MissionResult"/>
   </jms-queue>
   ```

   what should i put in the `match` attribute in order to match it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer:

1. The 2 definitions can co-exist. Jboss will find the best match.
2. You need to define a queue like:

   ```
   <jms-queue name="exampleQueue">
      <entry name="queue/exampleQueue" />
   </jms-queue>
   ```

   and then to match this queue, use `jms.queue.exampleQueue`.

Comment: One thing I should add is that the 'match' attribute uses Camel case to distinguish Queue names. So if your Queue name is defined as name="EmailQueue" then your 'match'  value will be "jms.queue.emailQueue" and not "jms.queue.EmailQueue". If you use the latest then it will silently be ignored and the default (wildcard) one will be used.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to the manual and can you clarify the 'best match', please? (does 'best match' mean the strictest? Or will it stack matches?